# How to get categories value from wordpress widget categories dropdown

Tags: wordpress

I am try to build a wordpress widget which will list categories and a input field for number of posts in widget section which works perfectly, 
but the problem is when i try to get the values from the dropdown category section to my code which will output selected category posts i am not getting the category id, for testing purpose i have added these two lines:

```
  echo $catno; /*tested  got right output as 5*/
 echo $catid; /*tested but no output*/
```

where i am making and error i don't know
here is my Full widget Code:

```
class category_one extends WP_Widget {

    // constructor
    function category_one() {
            parent::WP_Widget(false, $name = __('Category One', 'wp_widget_plugin') );

    }

// widget form creation
function form($instance) {

// Check values
if( $instance) {
     $catid = $instance['catid'];
     $catno = esc_attr($instance['catno']);


} else {
     $catid = '';
     $catno = '';

}
?>

<p>
<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('catid'); ?>"><?php _e('Select Category', 'wp_widget_plugin'); ?></label>
 <?php wp_dropdown_categories( array( 'name' => $this->get_field_name("catid"), 'selected' => $instance["catid"] ) ); ?>
</p>

<p>
<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('catno'); ?>"><?php _e('No Posts', 'wp_widget_plugin'); ?></label>
<input class="catone" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('catno'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('catno'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $catno; ?>" />
</p>
<?php
}


function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
      $instance = $old_instance;
      // Fields
      $instance['catid'] = $new_instance['catid'];
      $instance['catno'] = $new_instance['catno'];

     return $instance;
}





   // display widget
function widget($args, $instance) {
   extract( $args );

   // these are the widget options
   $catid = $instance['catid'];
   $catno = $instance['catno'];

   echo $before_widget;
  echo $catno; /*tested  got right output*/
 echo $catid; /*tested but no output  got right output*/
global $post;

if (!$catid) { }
else {
$myposts = get_posts(array('numberposts' => $catno, 'offset' => 0, 'category__in' => array($catid), 'post_status'=>'publish', 'order'=>'DEC' ));
echo '<div class="catlist">';

echo '<h2 class="sidebar_title"><a href="' . get_category_link($catid) . '" title="'. get_cat_name($catid) .'">' . get_cat_name($catid) . '</a></h4>';
echo "<ul class='widget_catlist'>";
foreach($myposts as $post) :
setup_postdata($post);

echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="'. get_the_title() .'">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';
 endforeach; 
wp_reset_query(); 
 echo "</ul>";
echo '</div>'; 
}
   echo $after_widget;


}
}

// register widget
add_action('widgets_init', create_function('', 'return register_widget("category_one");')); 
?>
```